# cloud foundry : manifest.yml services setting

Tags: cloud, manifest, cloud-foundry

We have a manifest.yml with following :
For DEV environment: (database)

services:
 - project_database

FOr Test And PROd:

services:
 - project_schema

currently we are manually editing to switch between project_database and project_schema when deploying to different environments.

Is there a way i can set in manifest file if PROD use project_schema and if DEV use Project_database

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I think your best bet is to create two files, manifest-dev.yml and manifest-prod.yml. You can select with, for example, cf push -f manifest-prod.yml.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few different ways to tackle this. This simplest approach would be to define both your development and production applications in one file. If you wished to add a route that you could map / unmap between dev and production, you could do that too.

I guess another approach would be to have the application introspectively look at the space name it's been pushed to (via environment variables) and then based on the space switch datasource to one that has been tagged 'dev' or 'production' but that all seems like an anti-pattern.

For a breakdown on how to define multiple applications in one manifest, take a read through https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#multi-apps, it should give you some idea of how to solve this.